# How to add name of project or group in 'author' field in bibtex?

Tags: bibtex

So I want to include list of authors classically separated by 'and', but at the end I want to have the name of that group or the project they were working on. 
I want to get something like this for instance, in bibliography:

"N. Suzuki et al. (Planck Colaboration)"

Is there an additional field that I can use, or some special way in which I could add this name to the 'author' field?

Edit:
I am currently using 'abbrv' style, but it is not really satisfying, because I would like to have field 'year' displayed before field 'pages' both for journals and for books.

Comment: You should at least say which bibliography style you're using.

Comment: Is `biblatex` a possibility for you`?

Comment: Well why not, I've just tried biblatex. Though, it brought me more problems than solutions. Anyway, how can I modify these fields in bibliography with biblatex?